# scala.sys.process error Cannot run program "dir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: scala, terminal, process

i want to use scala to run the terminal command, and try to use scala.sys.process. but the error show like that:   *Cannot run program "dir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file* specified

```
 import scala.sys.process._
    val res = "DIR".!
        println(res)
```

does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: `DIR` is probably a shell command and not a stand-alone program. If it **is** a stand-alone program then you'll likely need to use the complete file name: `dir.exe`

Comment: i have tried, but still not work

Comment: _What_ have you tried? What OS are you running? Is `DIR` a stand-alone program? Where is the executable in the file system? You've provided none of the information needed to help you.

Comment: windows, dir is shell command for windows

Comment: I don't know windows. If you're right that `dir` is _not_ a stand-alone program then you'll likely need to invoke the shell program and pass `"dir"` as an argument to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unix/Linux, then commands and files are case sensitive so you need to change to `dir`. On Windows case doesn't matter for commands. This works on Linux:

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> val res = "dir".!
test_file.txt
val res: Int = 0
```

Comment: that is what i did, but there is error: Cannot run program "dir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @kailing can you provide info about your OS and shell? Alternatively to `dir` you can use `ls`. What happens when you run `dir` from the same shell without Scala?

Comment: i used the windows, and IDE is intelij